# asp.net mvc route keyword to action in controller in in different namespace

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have an array of strings like this: `var apps = new[] { "foo", "bar" }`. I wish to route these words to a specific action in a controller within a different namespace in an other project. My latest attempt looked like this (global.asax):

```
foreach (var app in apps)
{
    routes.MapRoute(
            name: app,
            url: app,
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = app },
            namespaces: new [] { "The.Namespace.Controllers" });
}
```

The project containing the controller is a web project pointing to `/apps` in the local IIS with its own route config. The action looks like this:

```
[Route("foo")]
public ActionResult Foo() {
    // ...
    return View("Foo");
}
```

Calling `example.com/apps/foo` is working, `example.com/foo` doesn't (different errors with different approaches). Any ideas how I could solve the issue?

Comment: Is the project with the controllers added as a dependency in the project where you are configuring the routing?

Comment: I believe it's not; the project was just created. Is it necessary?

Comment: Yes, otherwise MVC won't be able to instantiate the controller. The other option is, instead of routing, create an action to redirect the request to other url, the best approach depends on your requirements.

Comment: We're changing our project structure.  Customers may have bookmarked the old urls. I will check if we can add the dependency if it does now exist. Thank you.